# Loopback's ReferenceMany-like relation with additional fields

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, embedding

I need help with *loopback framework*.
I have two models: Post and Media. 
Examples:

**Media**

```
{
  id: ObjectId("...a1"), 
  type: "gif",
  path: "some/folder"
},

{
  id: ObjectId("...a2"), 
  type: "mp4",
  path: "some/folder"
},
```

**Post**

```
{
  id: ObjectId("...b1"), 
  title: "Apollo 13",
  content: [
    {
      mediaId: ObjectId("...a1"), 
      header: "header-1",
      description: "descr-1"
    },
    {
      mediaId: ObjectId("...a2"), 
      header: "header-2",
      description: "descr-2"
    }
  ]
},

{
  id: ObjectId("...b2"), 
  title: "2 seconds to Moon",
  content: [
    {
      mediaId: ObjectId("...a1"), 
      header: "header-3",
      description: "descr-3"
    },
  ]
}
```

As you can guess I'm going to use MongoDb. I want to describe a relation between this two models, but not sure how to do it in the right way.

If I had only array of `mediaId`s, I'd make it through `referenceMany`. Now it's look more like `embedsMany`, but embeds many *what*?

I even tried to make something like `MediaItem` model and give it `transient` datasource. But I didn't make it works right with rest APIs.

At final I want to get one or many *posts* with including *media* data such as `type` and `path` fields.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use HasManyThrough relation (http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasManyThrough-relations.html) and then include filter (http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html)

Comment: With `hasManyThrough` relation I will have to move field `content` out of the `post` model. It's not what I want to do.

Comment: Two questions: Why `content` field have to be in `post`?
Why you tried to give `MediaItem` model transient datasource? (why not mongoDB)